# Column count, integer value, Data truncated and some other messages

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, truncate, truncated

I've been struggling with my database for a while now and my teacher is nearly impossible to get a hold of. My code is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `database28`.`activity`
VALUES
("Stefan", 1.1.2.2, "Dator", "Mozilla" );

INSERT INTO `database28`.`activity`
VALUES
("Ulf", 1.1.3.3, "Mobil", "Safari" );

INSERT INTO `database28`.`activity`
VALUES
("Göran", 1.1.4.4, "surfplatta", "opera" );

INSERT INTO `database28`.`activity`
VALUES
("Berit", 1.1.5.5, "Dator", "Internet Explorer");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`activity`
VALUES
("Arne", 1.1.6.6, "Mobil", "Chrome");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`destination`
(`Destination`,
`Direction`,
`Klient`)
VALUES
("Databas1", "Till", "Privat");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`destination`
(`Destination`,
`Direction`,
`Klient`)
VALUES
("Databas2", "Till", "Företag");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`destination`
(`Destination`,
`Direction`,
`Klient`)
VALUES
("Databas2", "Till", "Privat");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`destination`
(`Destination`,
`Direction`,
`Klient`)
VALUES
("Databas2", "Från", "Privat");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`destination`
(`Destination`,
`Direction`,
`Klient`)
VALUES
("Databas2", "Från", "Företag");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`destination`
(`Destination`,
`Direction`,
`Klient`)
VALUES
("Databas1", "Till", "Privat");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`eventtype`
(`EventID`,
`Namn`)
VALUES
("Success Audit");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`eventtype`
(`EventID`,
`Namn`)
VALUES
("failure Audit");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`eventtype`
(`EventID`,
`Namn`)
VALUES
("Information");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`eventtype`
(`EventID`,
`Namn`)
VALUES
("Warning");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`eventtype`
(`EventID`,
`Namn`)
VALUES
("Error");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`log`
(`LogID`,
`Tid`,
`Serverr`,
`ActID`,
`Destination`,
`Källa`)
VALUES
(1, 11:00, "Server 1", "Stefan", "Databas1", "System");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`log`
(`LogID`,
`Tid`,
`Serverr`,
`ActID`,
`Destination`,
`Källa`)
VALUES
(2, 12:00, "Server 2", "Ulf", "Databas2", "exe");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`log`
(`LogID`,
`Tid`,
`Serverr`,
`ActID`,
`Destination`,
`Källa`)
VALUES
(3, 13:00, "Server 1", "Mats", "Databas1", "System");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`log`
(`LogID`,
`Tid`,
`Serverr`,
`ActID`,
`Destination`,
`Källa`)
VALUES
(2, 11:00, "Server 1", "Arne", "Databas1", "exe");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`log`
(`LogID`,
`Tid`,
`Serverr`,
`ActID`,
`Destination`,
`Källa`)
VALUES
(3, 21:00, "Server 1", "Berit", "Databas1", "exe");
```

This however leaves me with several error messages, i dont get them all at once of course but when i try and change something i seem to be making it worse. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put `QUOTE Mark` in Insert query of `activity` table and `log` table

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `database28`.`activity`
VALUES
("Stefan", '1.1.2.2', "Dator", "Mozilla" );

INSERT INTO `database28`.`activity`
VALUES
("Ulf", '1.1.3.3', "Mobil", "Safari" );

INSERT INTO `database28`.`activity`
VALUES
("Göran", '1.1.4.4', "surfplatta", "opera" );

INSERT INTO `database28`.`activity`
VALUES
("Berit", '1.1.5.5', "Dator", "Internet Explorer");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`activity`
VALUES
("Arne", '1.1.6.6', "Mobil", "Chrome");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`destination`
(`Destination`,
`Direction`,
`Klient`)
VALUES
("Databas1", "Till", "Privat");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`destination`
(`Destination`,
`Direction`,
`Klient`)
VALUES
("Databas2", "Till", "Företag");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`destination`
(`Destination`,
`Direction`,
`Klient`)
VALUES
("Databas2", "Till", "Privat");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`destination`
(`Destination`,
`Direction`,
`Klient`)
VALUES
("Databas2", "Från", "Privat");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`destination`
(`Destination`,
`Direction`,
`Klient`)
VALUES
("Databas2", "Från", "Företag");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`destination`
(`Destination`,
`Direction`,
`Klient`)
VALUES
("Databas1", "Till", "Privat");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`eventtype`
(`EventID`,
`Namn`)
VALUES
("Success Audit");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`eventtype`
(`EventID`,
`Namn`)
VALUES
("failure Audit");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`eventtype`
(`EventID`,
`Namn`)
VALUES
("Information");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`eventtype`
(`EventID`,
`Namn`)
VALUES
("Warning");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`eventtype`
(`EventID`,
`Namn`)
VALUES
("Error");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`log`
(`LogID`,
`Tid`,
`Serverr`,
`ActID`,
`Destination`,
`Källa`)
VALUES
(1, '11:00', "Server 1", "Stefan", "Databas1", "System");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`log`
(`LogID`,
`Tid`,
`Serverr`,
`ActID`,
`Destination`,
`Källa`)
VALUES
(2, '12:00', "Server 2", "Ulf", "Databas2", "exe");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`log`
(`LogID`,
`Tid`,
`Serverr`,
`ActID`,
`Destination`,
`Källa`)
VALUES
(3, '13:00', "Server 1", "Mats", "Databas1", "System");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`log`
(`LogID`,
`Tid`,
`Serverr`,
`ActID`,
`Destination`,
`Källa`)
VALUES
(2, '11:00', "Server 1", "Arne", "Databas1", "exe");

INSERT INTO `database28`.`log`
(`LogID`,
`Tid`,
`Serverr`,
`ActID`,
`Destination`,
`Källa`)
VALUES
(3, '21:00', "Server 1", "Berit", "Databas1", "exe");
```

Comment: Ah thanks! Now all the other error messages went away however a new one came up
"Duplicate entry 'Stefan' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @user3106867 Then remove that insert statement

Comment: And by that u mean removing "Stefan" from the
INSERT INTO `database28`.`activity`
VALUES
("Stefan", '1.1.2.2', "Dator", "Mozilla" );
?

Comment: @user3106867 You have to remove the INSERT statements which are already inserted in respective tables

Comment: aha, so all of them should be removed. makes sense now. hehe, sorry im new to this.